# How do I implement a Google Latitude check-in feature on Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, google-latitude

I hope this is the correct forum. I wish to write a mobile application (MVC 4 mobile app) that extends Google Latitude for Windows Mobile 7 (or version 8 when launched in November). However, according to Google's own website (see http://www.google.com/mobile/latitude/), the check-in feature is not supported on Windows Mobile. So, how would I implement such a feature (not so interested in the UI here) using the technologies that I have mentioned?

**EDIT**

The implementation needs to store check-in data against a Google Latitude account.

Comment: Doesn't Bing Maps have that feature?

Comment: It may have a similar feature; also Facebook has a check-in feature but it doesn't store data against the Google Latitude account. I think I may need to re-specify the question.